# Ng-model not being put into object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select form in which I load data in shown here:

```
<select id="selectgroep" name="selectgroep" class="form-control" size='5' ng-model="afspraak.groep" ng-options="t.id as t.id for t in objecten">
</select>
```

And my object shown here:

```
$scope.afspraak = {     
    groep: '',
};
```

Shouldn't the data that I choose in the select form go into `afspraak.groep`? I have console logged it and it doesn't go in.

In a different partial I have made the exact same and it does do what I want it to do. I have compared the two at least 20 times, but I do not see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: could you show the snippets of the working case? actually a little bit more of your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
function test(afspraak){
  $scope.afspraak = {     
     groep: afspraak.groep
 };
}
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.afspraak = {
    groep: '',
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="afspraak.groep">
    <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <p>{{afspraak.groep}}!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried that way and it doesn't work. I need to fill the options with data I retrieve, so I either use ng-options or I put an ng-repeat to an option field. Both doesn't seem to work.